# How to access in map having a pair inside it

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-pair

I am using the map with pair inside it,
but not able to figure out how to access with iterator of map

my map declaration

```
  map<ll,pair<ll,ll> > val;
  map<ll,pair<ll,ll> > ::iterator it;
```

What i am using for accessing inserted values is

```
   cout<<it->first<<" " <<it->second->first<<" " <<it->second->second<<endl;
```

But the compiler is showing this error

```
error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::pair<long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int>'|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.` to access the elements of a pair.

```
cout<<it->first<<" " <<it->second.first<<" " <<it->second.second<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `->` to access the element pointed to by a pointer and a `.` to access a member variable. In this case, `map` is a container and `pair` a struct so you have to access the elements of both with `.`.

```
cout << it->first << " " << it->second.first << " " << it->second.second << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also return pair values together.

```
map<ll,pair<ll,ll> > val;

auto [pair_first_element,pair_second_element]=val[key_value];
```